# MySQL loop for use with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql

I have a set of raw data files named using a pattern like a-1.txt, a-2.txt, etc. I am using the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE command in a MySQL script to load the raw data files into the database. That command cannot be run in a stored procedure. I'd like to avoid doing a copy/paste for loading 20 raw data files, like I described, in the MySQL script and would much rather use a LOOP to load the raw data files, but LOOP cannot be used outside of a stored procedure.

What's the best way to handle this? How do I get the MySQL script to do this?

Comment: I would use a script, written in Ruby, Python, or Bash.

Comment: I almost never use MySQL stored procedures, for any type of query, not just LOAD DATA INFILE. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57414599/20860

Comment: The stored procedures are very useful in processing the raw data in the a-*.txt files into the actual tables.

Comment: Well then you could LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE first from a script, and then call your stored procedure to process the data. Although I would still not use a stored procedure for that. It's easier to do almost any type of code outside a stored procedure.

Comment: So this gets back to my original question. I can't use LOOP in a script, only in a stored procedure. So, in my script, is there some way I can loop through a set of files so that I can use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE?

Comment: Uh, with all due respect, have you ever written a script? [Bash Beginner's Guide: the for loop](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_01.html)

Comment: A MySQL script? Sure, plenty.

Comment: I added clarifying text in the description.

Comment: Right, MySQL scripts don't support loops. That's why I suggested a more full-featured scripting language like Ruby, Python, or Bash. They support looping control structures. Any other programming language would work too, like Java or C#, but scripts tend to be quicker to write for short tasks like this. SQL was always meant to be used in cooperation with some more full-featured language.

Comment: The application that uses the database is written in Java, and I'm using Eclipse and Ant to control the build tasks such as this one, but I'll look into Ant tasks that can call a Ruby, Python, or Bash script. Thanks.

Comment: If you're already using Java, you can do a loop in Java. I only suggested a script with the assumption that you _weren't_ using another application programming language. Feel free to do the loop in Java directly. You can make a loop in Java code and format the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE statement as a string, then run that statement via JDBC, or if you prefer a data access library like jOOQ.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Bash, you can run the following to generate the SQL file.

```
rm testfile.sql
ls *.txt | xargs -I inputfile echo "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'inputfile' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';" >> testfile.sql
```

Then to run it, you can add another line.

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -pXXXXXXX mydatabase < testfile.sql
```